# Linkedin Login Authentication Error in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, oauth, linkedin-api, csrf

I'm having issues authenticating my app with LinkedIn to get a user's SESSIONID to be stored locally in my flutter app.

when I make a post request with this URL: "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/authenticate". I get a status code of 401, with the following data

```
login_result: CHALLENGE, challenge_url: https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/direct-login-submit?addDetailedLoginResult=add&dropLiatCookie=drop&csrfToken=ajax%3A8991541585167414413&pSIdString=4a184f28-1923-454f-9025-16e7b2fc83bd&ut=3Ch64d1O6Yhqo1
```

when I make another post request with this other URL: "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit". I get a status code of 200, with the SESSIONID, but not logged into LinkedIn (It returns the LinkedIn HTML signing page code).

What is the current base URL to send a login post request to LinkedIn using these parameters: `{'session_key': email, 'session_password': password}`??

I want to be able to get the LinkedIn contacts of a logged-in user.